# Is including an external CSS file safe, or could it lead to code injection?

Tags: javascript, css, security, xss

I'm working on a site that customers will use by embedding it in an iframe in their site.  I want to give them the ability to customize the styling of the contents so they can make it fit in with the styles of their site.

The basic idea I have is to let them give me the URL to a CSS file I should include in the page I serve to them to fill the iframe.  As far as I know this is safe, but I'm not particularly familiar with CSS (especially the newer versions), so I want to verify this.

Is there any way someone could construct a CSS file that would let them inject code into my site or otherwise gain access to things like my domain's cookies?  Is this really safe, or do I need to come up with a different solution?

Comment: I think you'd be better off allowing users to paste custom styles into a textarea and then you can validate that it is actually CSS and nothing harmful before including it in your views.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No it is unsafe.  `expression` and `-moz-binding` are known ways to cause arbitrary script execution on certain browsers via CSS.  [LiveJournal](http://www.davidpashley.com/blog/computing/livejournal-mozilla-bug.html) suffered a very public XSS attack that was due to JavaScript embedded in user-supplied CSS.

> With Mozilla deciding to allow the execution of arbitrary JavaScript via CSS, there is no other viable solution than the one we have undertaken.

From [Caja's attack vector wiki](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/CssAllowsArbitraryCodeExecution):

> Crafted CSS stylesheets can execute unsanitized javascript in the global scope on some browsers.
>
> **Background**
>
> CSS includes several mechanisms for changing the surrounding markup and executing expressions.
>
> IE has an extension that allows execution of arbitrary javascript. The `expression` property is described at http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634.aspx
>
> Using the power of dynamic properties, it is now possible to declare property values not only as constants, but also as formulas. ... For scripting, a dynamic property can be any legal JScript or Microsoft Visual Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript) statement.
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533503.aspx
>
> `binding` allows binding to externally specified scripts
>   http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS:-moz-binding & http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XBL:XBL_1.0_Reference:Elements#binding
>
> `-moz-binding` allows binding via the XML interface (also using data: URLs)
>
> **Assumptions**
>
> Untrusted code can generate style elements or style attributes or otherwise add arbitrary CSS rules and create DOM elements that trigger those rules.
>
> **Versions**
>
> IE 5 and later (but not IE 8 or later in "standards mode").
>
> Mozilla/Firefox, versions not known.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the background.  Looks like I'll have to have another mechanism for them to provide styling, one where I can sanitize it first.
Now to figure out how to sanitize the CSS...

Comment: The Caja project keeps [white lists](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/CajaWhitelists) of CSS properties and values which can be useful.  It also has a Java parser and sanitizer built in.

Comment: Caja has moved to Github, the white lists can be found here: https://github.com/google/caja/tree/master/src/com/google/caja/lang/css